# Why is the count off by one?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on some exams in Python and I have a question.
For example, we have 1000 lines of some words. In each line, there are 2 words separated by a space button (ASCII code 32). And I have to write code in Python to check if the first word exists in the second one (in the same line), for example, `adc` exists in `addadc` but not in `addadfc`, and I need to count all lines that are good. The result is `235`, but it is too high, as the correct answer is `234`. I don't know why this is happening.

Code:

```
liczba_wierszy = 0 #amount of lines

for i in range(1000):
    linia = input() # line
    index_spacji = 0 # space index
    index_konca = 0 #index of the word
    pierwszy_napis = "" # first word
    drugi_napis = ""  # second word
    for j in linia:
        if ord(j)!= 32:
            index_spacji+=1
        else:
            break;
    pierwszy_napis =(linia[0:index_spacji-1])
    drugi_napis = (linia[index_spacji+1:len(linia)])
    if pierwszy_napis in drugi_napis:
        liczba_wierszy+=1

print(liczba_wierszy)
```

It's written in Polish so I'll translate it a little bit.

Comment: Try with range(10) and see if you still get a result one higher than desired. Test with other numbers like range(1) , range(2), range(500). That could lead you to your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I give you a simple alternative?

```
count = 0
for i in range(1000):
    line = input().strip()
    word1,word2 = line.split(' ')
    if word1 in word2:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Also I see that you have initialised strings for `word1` and `word2` as `""` and later reassigned values to them. You might want to note that Python strings are immutable and reassigning to them later will create a new object anyway. So if you are going with your code skip the initialization part.

Comment: I've used yours, and I've seen that the .strip() method didn't change anything, so I guess it just removes spaces from the start and end of the line. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in this line:

`pierwszy_napis =(linia[0:index_spacji-1])`

It's putting one less character in `pierwszy_napis` than it should. Because MyString[a:b] gives you the substring from index a to index b - 1.

Try

`pierwszy_napis =(linia[0:index_spacji])`

instead

Comment: word1 = "abcde"; word2 = "abcdf"